# How to use Min If in VBA (to find the minimum value for specific condition)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have MsgBox to show the  minimum value of status XXX.
For the table below, I would expect to see "3"

Can I use this?:

```
MsgBox "=MINIFS(range("B:B"),range("A:A"),""XXX"")"
```

| Status | value |
| --- | --- |
| Column A | Column B |
| YYY | 1 |
| XXX | 7 |
| YYY | 4 |
| XXX | 3 |

```
MsgBox "=MINIFS(range("B:B"),range("A:A"),""XXX"")"
```

I expect to see "3"

Comment: See how `range` is not capitalized? That's the first sign you are doing something wrong. When you put a `Range` inside a `String` like that, it does not get evaluated and instead is seen as a literal `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a formula within VBA you have to call it via `application.worksheetfunction`:

```vb
Sub showMinimumValueForStatus(Status As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '--->> adjust this to your needs

Dim rg As Range
Set rg = ws.UsedRange.Columns("A:B")

Dim x As Long
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(rg.Columns(2), rg.Columns(1), Status)

MsgBox "Minimum value of " & Status & " is " & x

End Sub
```

Furthermore you should always explicitly refer to a range by its worksheet. Otherwise active sheet will be referenced.

Comment: Perfect! As you are new to SO: please accept the answer - and maybe upvote it. Thanks

Comment: sure, I accepted the answer but I still cannot vote. Thanks again.